# MVC validation focusing the date time control on validation fail

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having my view as follows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Leave", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
       Leave Type
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LeaveTypeId, Model.LeaveType, "Choose...", new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = "1" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LeaveTypeId, "", new { @class = "label-danger" })
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      From Date
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = "2" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromDate, "", new { @class = "label-danger" })
   </div>
   </div>
}
```

[image]

When I click on apply button it is auto focusing the next control as my tab index was set. So is there any way to focus but not display the datetime control

Comment: I assume this is the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (and not a jquery plugin)?